# DoS -> Denial of Service tag synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I propose that the [dos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dos) and [ddos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddos) tags are replaced with [denial-of-service](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service), and synonyms are set up appropriately. This provides absolute clarity, rather than an ambiguous acronym. The new tag should also encompass non-flood attacks, such as exploiting poor incorrect password blocking systems.

Users should be encouraged to combine this tag with other tags for specific types of attacks, e.g. [syn-flood](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syn-flood).

The problem is that the tag names are always lowercase, and there are other things that might come under the "DOS" acronym, e.g. Distributed Operating System, Distributed Object System, Disk Operating System, Data Over Signalling, etc.

I also don't think we need a separate tag specifically for distributed attacks, since the distinction is minimal and most [ddos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddos) questions also get tagged as [dos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dos).

Thoughts?

Comment: I like that. If there are no objections, I will setup the synonyms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree wrt [dos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dos) as a synonym to [denial-of-service](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service) - I think that is a good idea, and as @Hendrik said, if there are no objections he will set it up.

However I dont agree about [ddos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddos) - though in effect the actual outcome is pretty much the same (no service), it is a different type of attack, with different solutions for different scenarios.
I'll admit, in many questions the asker is confused, and doesnt really know which one he means - but *we* do, and I think these are really different situations.

Comment: Sounds a fair comprimise. Do we use `ddos`, or `distributed-denial-of-service`? imo, the latter is too wordy, the former is possibly too short. Perhaps `ddos-attack`? Maybe `attack` is redundant though. Hmm...

Comment: Perhaps a solution would be to have a generic `distributed-attack` tag, to cover all types of distributed attack. Then we've got `denial-of-service` and `distributed-attack` in combination to cover the DDoS angle. Or maybe I'm making things complicated... O_o

Comment: ddos works fine imo. It is clear enough what it means, especially in the context of this site.

Comment: Agree with dos as synonym to denial-of-service, but reckon we keep ddos, as @AviD says.

Comment: I think we're agreed then :-)